# React - how to test onScroll event on window.document?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have a component that registers a scroll event like so:

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (document) document.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
}

onScroll() {
    // do something...
}
```

I need to test to make sure that the onScroll function fires when the document scrolls. How do I do this (preferably using Enzyme?